# Apache proxy node.js No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, proxy

I have application build on node.js running at port 3000 (A  http://localhost:3000)

Here is rules for allowing cross domain requests:

```
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        // Website you wish to allow to connect
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:64263');

        // Request methods you wish to allow
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

        // Request headers you wish to allow
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

        // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
        // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
        //res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

        // Pass to next layer of middleware
        next();
  });
```

I configured virtual host on apache (B) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  live-chat.dev

    DirectoryIndex index.html 
    DocumentRoot C:\xampp\projects\service

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Also i have another web application (C) developed using php.
The problem is: When i'm trying to send ajax request from C to A directly it works without any error, But when i send requests to B it returns error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://live-chat.dev/categories. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:64263' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: If (C) is also running on localhost, can you open `http://live-chat.dev/categories` from local browser and 1) check if you are reaching node app 2) inspect headers and see if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is there

Comment: I have send request to http://live-chat.dev/categories /  not to http://live-chat.dev/categories and it worked. Looking for answers why i can't send requests to http://live-chat.dev/categories without last "/"

Comment: does `http://localhost:3000/categories` work?

Comment: yes it works. correctly. Maybe it depends on apache virutal host config ?